# How do I configure the format of the Karma log?

Tags: testing, karma-runner

I would like to change the format of my Karma (nee Testacular) log.  Out of the box, it looks like this:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:8080/
```

The docs say to look at log4js for other loggers, the default being [{type:'console'}]. So I started by adding just that much to my Karma config file:

```
loggers = [{ type: 'console'}]
```

and was pleasantly surprised to see that the log output looked like

```
[2013-05-29 11:23:55.807] [INFO] karma - Karma server started at http://localhost:8080/
```

Halfway there. Now I want to show a shorter message. After looking at log4j, I tried each of the following

```
loggers = [{ type: 'console', PatternLayout:'%d{HH:mm:ss} %m'}]
loggers = [{ type: 'console', ConversionPattern:'%d{HH:mm:ss} %m'}]
```

neither of which changed the result.  The log4j docs say

> The PatternLayout class extends the abstract org.apache.log4j.Layout class and overrides the format> () method to structure logging information according to a supplied pattern.

Is this just not even implemented in Karma or have I just not found the magic keyword?

Answer (score 2):

Karma uses [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node). Try this:

```
loggers: [{type: 'console', pattern: '%d{HH:mm:ss} %m'}]
```